# Codeblocks Issue

Tags: c, codeblocks

I recently started a C class and I'm encountering issues getting Codeblocks to work. I use a mac, so I downloaded Xcode ads well as the command line tools.

When I click "build and run" on a correct program (provided by prof.), the terminal does not show the prompts it is supposed to, but rather this message:

> Process returned 127 (0x7F)   execution time : 0.006 s Press ENTER to continue.

​When I click Enter, I receive this message repeatedly every time:

> Abirs-MacBook-Pro:~ abirfarhat$

I have tried re-installing codeblocks, went over the installation instructions and couldn't figure out what I missed. Is there anything I could do to fix this please?

Comment: *What* terminal? The output window inside Code:Blocks? The terminal you started Code:Blocks from? Some other terminal?

Comment: The terminal where the output is supposed to display, like for instance if the program asks the use to input a number, the terminal is where the prompt should appear.

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem, so we can help you debug it.